# Volume based encryption for different OS sharing the same disk

Tags: encryption, filevault, diskutil, disk-volume

On my macbook M1, I created two volumes (one for my professional activity and one for my personal activity). Each volume has it's own macOS. The goal is to prevent remote administrators of one of the OSs (the one used for the professional activity) to be able to even see the content of the other volume.

Here are some diskutil infos seen from each OS. **Volume 1 info seen from OS in Volume 1**:

```
Volume type : APFS Startup Snapshot
BSD device node : disk3s1s1
System : macOS 13.2.1 (22D68)
File system : APFS (Encrypted)
Owners enabled : Yes
Is encrypted : Yes
Bootable : Yes
```

**Volume 2 info seen from OS in Volume 2**:

```
Volume type : APFS Startup Snapshot
BSD device node : disk3s8s1
System : macOS 12.3 (21E230)
File system : APFS
Owners enabled : No
Is encrypted : No (Encrypted at rest)
Bootable : Yes
```

and **Volume 2 info seen from OS in Volume 1**:

```
Volume type : APFS System Volume
BSD device node : disk3s8
System : macOS 12.3 (21E230)
File system : APFS
Owners enabled : Yes
Is encrypted : No (Encrypted at rest)
Bootable : Yes
```

I wanted to encrypt **Volume 1** and enabled FileFault. However, from within **Volume 2**, I'm still able to read (and even write) to **Volume 1**. Is it expected behaviour?

LMK if more info are required, I will update the question.

Comment: Wouldn't just using separate user accounts be sufficient? How will apps 'read private stuff'?

Comment: If clear and fully robust separation between work and private is needed, you should use different Macs connected to different LANs (or with file sharing disabled).  Anything else will be a compromise.

Comment: Thanks. I added clarification regarding the purpose. The purpose is to prevent remote administrators to even see the content of the other volume. This what I meant by "apps read private stuff". Having two different machines is not an option.